# Thinkpad W540 internal input devices not detected in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: keyboard, 15.04, xorg, lightdm, thinkpad

The touchpad, trackpoint, and keyboard aren't detected after boot. I know that the keyboard still works because I can use it to navigate the BIOS. Looking at my X server's log, I can see that my external (USB) input devices are initialized as well as the internal webcam, but I don't see any mention of the missing devices. I didn't see any ignore rules in `/etc/shared/X11/xorg.conf.d`, either. I previously had Ubuntu 14.04 installed, and the keyboard and touchpad worked then, but they haven't worked since I formatted my hard drive and installed 15.04. I have LightDM 1.14.2, X Server 1.17.1, and my kernel is version 3.19.0-30-generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to have been caused by booting with either the `acpi=off` or `noapic` flags set. I reproduced the issue with a W541 using those boot options, and with them removed, the input devices work.